# serializearray() jquery fields to JSON by rows

Tags: jquery, json

I use `serializearray()` jquery for serialize fields to JSON. It works good but i need it by row, every row has an ID called `"matricula"`.

[image]

I need someting like :

```
jsonObj = [{"matricula":"14002028","faltas":"1","calif":"9.30"},
           {"matricula":"14005038","faltas":"0","calif":"9.80"},
           {"matricula":"14005499","faltas":"2","calif":"9.50"}];
```

But my code shows me this :(

```
jsonObj = [{"matricula":"14002028","faltas":"1"},
           {"matricula":"14002028","calif":"9.5"},
           {"matricula":"14005038","faltas":"0"},
           {"matricula":"14005038","calif":"8.0"},
           {"matricula":"14005499","faltas":"2"},
           {"matricula":"14005499","calif":"10"}];
```

and this is my CODE:

```
var dataString = jQuery('#frm_CapCalif').serializeArray(); // Send data forms

       jsonObj = [];   // create JSON object
 jQuery.each(dataString, function(i, field){ // get each value serialize
          item = {}
          item ["matricula"] = field.name.substr(0,8);          
            if (field.name.substr(8,1)==='F')

            item ["faltas"]  = field.value;
              else
            item ["calif"]  = field.value;


     jsonObj.push(item);
                                           });
```

NOTE: Every field is named matricula&F and matricula&C  and that shows this "14005028F" and "14005028C" ... F means faltas and C means calif.

I think is so confused, is there a way to do this more simple? Thanks

Comment: I'd try removing the if else

Comment: When removed the IF THEN stataments, the values are repeated.

jsonObj = [{"matricula":"14002028","faltas":"1"},
           {"matricula":"14002028","calif":"1"},
           {"matricula":"14002034","faltas":"9.5"},
           {"matricula":"14002034","calif":"9.5"},
    {"matricula":"14004589","faltas":"1"},
           {"matricula":"14004589","calif":"1"}];

Comment: could you post what your dataString is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add item only if i is not odd. Something like this:

```
item = {};
jQuery.each(dataString, function(i, field){
     if (field.name.substr(8,1)==='F') item ["faltas"]  = field.value;
     else item ["calif"]  = field.value;

   if (i%2 != 0) {
    item ["matricula"] = field.name.substr(0,8);
    jsonObj.push(item);
    item = {};
   } 
});
```

Comment: I would ask you not to downvote other people one the single fact that they called your solution inferior.

Answer (score 0):

```
function groupByProperty(arr, prop) {
    var index = {}, output = [];
    $.each(arr, function (i, obj) {
        var propVal = obj[prop];
        if (!index.hasOwnProperty(propVal)) index[propVal] = {};
        index[propVal] = $.extend(index[propVal], obj);
    });
    $.each(index, function (key, value) {
        output.push(value);
    });
    return output;    
});
```

and

```
var test = [{"matricula":"14002028","faltas":"1"},
           {"matricula":"14002028","calif":"9.5"},
           {"matricula":"14005038","faltas":"0"},
           {"matricula":"14005038","calif":"8.0"},
           {"matricula":"14005499","faltas":"2"},
           {"matricula":"14005499","calif":"10"}];

groupByProperty(test, "matricula");
```

Comment: Hi,. this code has solved my problem
 if (i%2 != 0) {
    item ["matricula"] = field.name.substr(0,8);
    jsonObj.push(item);
    item = {};
   }

Comment: No. "copied and pasted the code it and it worked" and "the code did solve my problem" are not the same thing.

Comment: Why would you call my method inferior, when yours is almost same as mine plus more job. You get test variable, and then groupByProperty. Mine just gets test variable

Comment: Because it is inferior. Yours only works with the sample input exactly as given, mine would work with any input of this kind.

Comment: And there is way better general solution when yours. You do extra job here. You should form object in preferred format in a first place

Comment: I did not say mine was the best solution. It's better than yours, for very objective reasons. Yours is bad, for the same objective reasons. Downvote people who post bad solutions, not those whose critical remarks you don't like.